# Is it possible to style my style my non-gui python code and give it a good look?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask-restful, openstack-python-api

So I've this python program, non-GUI, just runs in the terminal, and I was wondering if I could style it, say with **html** and/or **css**, to make it look like a gui, well, just to add graphics and stuff like that. I've been doing research and so far I've come across the ***cgi module***, which doesn't quite match the criteria, I've also tried to engage in ***API development***, but don't know how to integrate the programs, anyone with a clue please? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create a GUI, using Tkinter or PyQt?

Comment: A Terminal is purely text based. Whcih means you can add colored text ascii symbols. It is possible to create some gui-like program, but you can't use html to show images, buttons etc.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://codeburst.io/building-beautiful-command-line-interfaces-with-python-26c7e1bb54df) could be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, they did help!